# vim TagList only generate tags in the Ctags58 folder

Tags: vim, exuberant-ctags, taglist

I'm in windows XP, and the vim TagList plugin only behaves correctly if the file I'm coding in is inside the Ctag58 folder. Otherwise it just genetats a list of my open files without tags.

I've tried adding the catalog to path and the vim command :let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='C:\Program\Ctags58\ctags.exe'
and it didn't work but then in.

I went through the the taglist  FAQ:

But the last to "dots" of part 1. of the
http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html 
were they speak of temp and tmp variables . I can't make heads or tails of that part.
Could this be my problem? How do i tell...

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm the question is not exactly clear ('it just genetats the file catalog' -- sure, that makes sense).

Without looking any further I'd suggest you add the path to the ctags.exe executable to your environment (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, advanced, environment, current user, PATH, edit, append `;C:\Program Files\Wherever\ctags\bin` (of course you'd have to use the ACTUAL path not this sample).

Then you'd need to restart VIM to test it

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formulation.It was a bad idea to write it at 4 am. Hopefully it a bit clearer now

Comment: I had this appened at path ;C:\Program\ctags58; when I first asked the qustion.

Comment: Yes, I put the Ctags files under program since i read that it could be problems if there was a space in the path name. And I get correct tags if i copy my codefile into the C:\Program\ctags58 folder. but the orginal doesn't get the tags

Comment: Ok. Well, the obvious thing is that taglist plugin is not finding the program unless it's in the current working directory, so there _must_ be something wrong with the path. As a brute force approach you might copy ctags.exe + dlls into the system32 folder, but it's not what I'd recommend